# what exactly WSDL file and how it will works with API integration with PHP?

Tags: php, api, wsdl

find some example file of WSDL , what is the work flow for this and how this work with API integration with PHP language.I am using WSDL soapclient for recent works,i am not more familiar with WSDL,  I wanted to know more about what exactly WSDL file do when we are working with WSDL file..

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
<s:element name="GetWeatherInformation">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetWeatherInformationResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetWeatherInformationResult" type="tns:ArrayOfWeatherDescription"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfWeatherDescription">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WeatherDescription" type="tns:WeatherDescription"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="WeatherDescription">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="WeatherID" type="s:short"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PictureURL" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCityForecastByZIPResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCityForecastByZIPResult" type="tns:ForecastReturn"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ForecastReturn">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Success" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResponseText" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="State" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="City" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WeatherStationCity" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ForecastResult" type="tns:ArrayOfForecast"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfForecast">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Forecast" nillable="true" type="tns:Forecast"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="Forecast">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Date" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="WeatherID" type="s:short"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Desciption" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Temperatures" type="tns:temp"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ProbabilityOfPrecipiation" type="tns:POP"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="temp">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MorningLow" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DaytimeHigh" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="POP">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Nighttime" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Daytime" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCityWeatherByZIPResult" type="tns:WeatherReturn"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="WeatherReturn">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Success" type="s:boolean"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResponseText" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="State" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="City" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WeatherStationCity" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="WeatherID" type="s:short"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Temperature" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RelativeHumidity" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Wind" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Pressure" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Visibility" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WindChill" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Remarks" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="ArrayOfWeatherDescription" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfWeatherDescription"/>
<s:element name="ForecastReturn" nillable="true" type="tns:ForecastReturn"/>
<s:element name="WeatherReturn" type="tns:WeatherReturn"/>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetWeatherInformationSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWeatherInformation"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetWeatherInformationSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWeatherInformationResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityForecastByZIPSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCityForecastByZIP"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityForecastByZIPSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIP"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetWeatherInformationHttpGetIn"/>
<wsdl:message name="GetWeatherInformationHttpGetOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:ArrayOfWeatherDescription"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityForecastByZIPHttpGetIn">
<wsdl:part name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityForecastByZIPHttpGetOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:ForecastReturn"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetIn">
<wsdl:part name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:WeatherReturn"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetWeatherInformationHttpPostIn"/>
<wsdl:message name="GetWeatherInformationHttpPostOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:ArrayOfWeatherDescription"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityForecastByZIPHttpPostIn">
<wsdl:part name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityForecastByZIPHttpPostOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:ForecastReturn"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostIn">
<wsdl:part name="ZIP" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:WeatherReturn"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="WeatherSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Gets Information for each WeatherID</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherInformationSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherInformationSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
Allows you to get your City Forecast Over the Next 7 Days, which is updated hourly. U.S. Only
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
Allows you to get your City's Weather, which is updated hourly. U.S. Only
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="WeatherHttpGet">
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Gets Information for each WeatherID</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherInformationHttpGetIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherInformationHttpGetOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
Allows you to get your City Forecast Over the Next 7 Days, which is updated hourly. U.S. Only
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPHttpGetIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPHttpGetOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
Allows you to get your City's Weather, which is updated hourly. U.S. Only
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="WeatherHttpPost">
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Gets Information for each WeatherID</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherInformationHttpPostIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherInformationHttpPostOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
Allows you to get your City Forecast Over the Next 7 Days, which is updated hourly. U.S. Only
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPHttpPostIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCityForecastByZIPHttpPostOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
Allows you to get your City's Weather, which is updated hourly. U.S. Only
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="WeatherSoap" type="tns:WeatherSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetWeatherInformation" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityForecastByZIP" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WeatherSoap12" type="tns:WeatherSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetWeatherInformation" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityForecastByZIP" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WeatherHttpGet" type="tns:WeatherHttpGet">
<http:binding verb="GET"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<http:operation location="/GetWeatherInformation"/>
<wsdl:input>
<http:urlEncoded/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<http:operation location="/GetCityForecastByZIP"/>
<wsdl:input>
<http:urlEncoded/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<http:operation location="/GetCityWeatherByZIP"/>
<wsdl:input>
<http:urlEncoded/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WeatherHttpPost" type="tns:WeatherHttpPost">
<http:binding verb="POST"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetWeatherInformation">
<http:operation location="/GetWeatherInformation"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityForecastByZIP">
<http:operation location="/GetCityForecastByZIP"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCityWeatherByZIP">
<http:operation location="/GetCityWeatherByZIP"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:mimeXml part="Body"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Weather">
<wsdl:port name="WeatherSoap" binding="tns:WeatherSoap">
<soap:address location="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WeatherSoap12" binding="tns:WeatherSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WeatherHttpGet" binding="tns:WeatherHttpGet">
<http:address location="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WeatherHttpPost" binding="tns:WeatherHttpPost">
<http:address location="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

A WSDL file is a description of a web service in XML format.

WSDL files are used to generate SOAP service clients. After you generate the client you can integrate with the SOAP service.

You can check out the php [SOAP client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

There are several different libraries in PHP that you can use to generate a client. Here are a couple available on github:

[wsdl2phpgenerater](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)

[WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)